# allow each domain to have it's own mail server name

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have apache2 running a few virtual hosts. Each of my websites is working properly.
I installed Postfix / Dovecot / MySQL and I can create the domains and users in it's database and everything works. What I'd like to change though is that all my domains must use the same POP3 and SMTP servernames (mail.maindomain.com). I'd like to allow each domain to use it's own servername (mail.otherdomain.com)

How do I do that?

Comment: I am far past the point of whining over a little rep loss. I know that it comes back a lot faster than it gets taken away, so don't take this as that type of comment. Why the downvote? If you'll comment on it, maybe I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you talk about just SMTP submission from your users:

Just create a DNS entry in `otherdomain.com` that points `mail.otherdomain.com` to the IP of your server with an `A` record or to `mail.maindomain.com` with a `CNAME`.

You might need to configure postfix to properly accept these names.

Comment: The DNS part, I understood, but how to configure postfix to accept them is the root of my question.

Comment: Also consider that to ensure deliverability, you should have a reverse DNS PTR record setup for you mail server. Can you have more than one of these per IP? Apparently so, but exercise caution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Multiple_pointer_records

I decided that having multiple mail server domains was a can of worms (hence not being able to help with the Postfix setup) and settled for one.

Comment: @jetboy I might also settle for one in my current install, but I am thinking about the future as I continue to grow as an administrator. Right now i have www.selahsanctuary.org and a few related domains that are all actually me, so I don't mind putting "mail.selahsanctuary.org" in my email client for my other domains. I'll keep looking though, so I can do this in the future. (my frame of reference is that where I work, we use a CPanel/WHM setup and everyone's email servernames are mail.domain.tld)